# sqlalchemy: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' for table schema attribute (pyodbc)

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to retrieve a table from an MSSQL server (using a DSN)

I have this code:

```
engine=sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://MATRIX')
md=sqlalchemy.MetaData()
tsk = sqlalchemy.Table('MATRIX_SMSIMA', md, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, schema='USER')
```

Initially, I tried it without the schema attribute and got an error message that pyodbc doesn't support a default schema.

When adding the schema attribute I get an error message that seems to stem from the guts of the Table function:

```
in _compile(element, compiler, **kw)
39 def _compile(element, compiler, **kw):
 40     from . import base
---> 41     if compiler.dialect.server_version_info < base.MS_2005_VERSION:
 42         return compiler.process(element.bindvalue, **kw)
 43     else:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Huh, that looks like it might be a bug in SQLAlchemy. Could you try monkey patching it to say `if int(compiler.dialect.server_version_info) < int(base.MS_2005_VERSION):`? I haven't tested it, but if that works, we could issue a pull request with a fix for the MSSQL dialect. I've contributed to the MSSQL dialect before and would be happy to issue a patch if it works.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have just found that the application I'm connecting to is working with InterSystems Cache SQL and not with MS SQL, so this is a false alarm